# Android Studio runs only in console mode on Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, shortcut

I have an issue with Android Studio on Ubuntu. Until now, I used to run Android Studio in console mode by going to the android-studio/bin folder and running studio.sh.
It works well, but it's boring for me type the commands each time I want to run it, I'd prefer to open it simply clicking on a shortcut. So, I tried to create a shortcut in my task bar.

In `/usr/share/applications`, I created a file named "android-studio.desktop". Here is the content of the file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Android Studio
Icon=/home/chugrothas/android-studio/bin/androidstudio.svg
Exec=/home/chugrothas/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

Then I dragged the desktop file onto the task bar.
When I try to open Android Studio using my new shortcut, I get :

> No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME
>   environment variable points to valid JDK installation.

However, when I run the command `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I get the following path :

> /home/chugrothas/jdk1.7.0_71

And in my `PATH` variable (just copying the end of the PATH content) :

> :/home/chugrothas/jdk1.7.0_71/bin

Because Android Studio works when I run it using command lines & because JAVA_HOME is correctly set, I don't understand why my shortcut does not work...

I searched on the internet and didn't find anybody in the same situation. It's not a big problem because I can still run AS, but I'd really like to understand why the shortcut does not work.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Looks like the variables are being set in the shell startup, probably eventually from `/etc/profile`, but not by your DE.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve this ? And what does DE stand for ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably your JAVA_HOME is not found here.

You can define it as a system-wide environment variable in /etc/environment eg. like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

and add the following line to the end:

```
JAVA_HOME="/home/chugrothas/jdk1.7.0_71"
```

Save and reboot your box.

Note: you can let Android Studio create the desktop entry on the Dash for you, eg. from the welcome window (Configure / Create Desktop Entry) or Tools / Create Desktop Entry... It will create the file jetbrains-android-studio.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this tested solution:

1)  Open gedit and enter the text below:

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Back up your data with one click
Exec=/home/jayant/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Icon=/home/jayant/android-studio/bin/idea.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;

change the path of Exec and Icon. save the file on desktop as .desktop extension and change the permission of file is executable.

2)  Execute the command to make your file executable: sudo chmod +x /home/jayant/android-studio/bin/studio.sh

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: I have tried this but this not working, Is there any other solution ?